# How can a .txt file content be imported/copied into a web text box?

Tags: python, selenium

A short explanation to the header. I'm trying to save a customer project on a website. The Project name is stored in a .txt file on my computer. The goal is to open up/export the txt content, and pasting/import it into a text box on the website.

```
folder = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@data-id='projNewFormInptName']")   
folder.send_keys("**imported .txt content**")
```

Thank you for your time lads.

Comment: so what's your question?

Comment: How can I import the content from a .txt file into a web text box

Comment: just read the content of the file into a string variable and pass that variable to `send_keys()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```py
file = open("file.txt")
content = file.read()
file.close()

folder = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@data-id='projNewFormInptName']")   
folder.send_keys(content)
```

`content` here is the entire content of the file `file.txt`.